# Is there a better way to do this python

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

Just started to learn Socket and Tkinter i want a cleaner and a better way to do this.The most important thing i want to get is automating label sizing so that it's height will be equal to it's counter

```
from tkinter import *
import socket

#Initialize Tkinter
win = Tk()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #Taking socket 
information

server = "pythonprogramming.net"
port = 80
server_ip = socket.gethostbyname(server)

frame_server_inventory = Frame(win, relief="raised", borderwidth=3)

label_tell_ip = Label(frame_server_inventory, text="IP:   " , borderwidth=3 , 
width=6, relief="raised",anchor="center")
label_tell_ip.grid(row=0 , column = 0) #Ip indicator

label_tell_header = Label(frame_server_inventory, 
text="Header",borderwidth=3,height=24,width=6, relief="raised")
label_tell_header.grid(row=18 , column=0)

frame_server_inventory.grid()

get_request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost:"+server+"\n\n"
sock.connect((server,port))
sock.send(get_request.encode())
result = sock.recv(2048)

frame_server_item= Frame(win,relief="raised",borderwidth=3)
frame_server_item.grid(row=0 , column=1)

label_ip = Label(frame_server_item, text=server_ip,borderwidth=3, width=70 , 
relief="raised")
label_ip.grid(row=0) # Displays Server IP

label_header = Label(frame_server_item, text= result, 
borderwidth=3,height=24,width=70 , relief="raised")
label_header.grid(row=1)


#Keeps The loop running
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: neither `send` nor `recv` is used correctly. Use some library (`httplib`, `requests`).

Comment: Thank you for your input sir